# How to change the properties or html inside wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I am new to WordPress and I have this project, that requires me to change the label of the fields in the admin page,

My plan is
1. locate the html file or php file
2. open the file
3. locate the  that I want to change
4. save it

Problem is I cant locate the file..

Steps that I took:
1. I went to the back end and locate the label that I want to change
2. I just simply point my mouse in the label, right click, and inspect it.
3. it the console window I click the source tab.
The goal of this steps is to see where the file lives and what is the name of the file.
images below for visual representation of the steps that I took
[image]

[image]

[image]

as you can see the file lives under wp-admin folder and the name of the file is post.php..

so I went to my server's C-panel to the file manager and try to locate the file, wp-admin folder is there, but the post.php is not present inside the folder, I open every file.. every .php .html file.. I still couldn't find the file or the label that I want to edit, I also went to wp-content, and open every file, I still couldn't find it.

Comment: Looked in the database?

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, there is nothing there, I located the post.php file by the way, but when I opened it, the code is not the same in the when I inspect the file.

Comment: that post.php file has lots of includes and other conditionals that generate the content. Some of those "labels" would come from the modules. Not sure on WP but on some other CMS the labels would be in the lang files. Might i reccomend using a command line and `GREP -rn "search term"`  Happy hunting

Comment: This "Properties" post type is either a plugin or created inside your theme. You gotta look for its Custom Fields definition. Search only for "home_area", without the prefix "property_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post .php file is a combination of includes, and it is a plug-in, what I did is I go to wp-content folder, and I click the name of the plug-in, and I just opened every folder and every file, until I found the code that I am looking for, every plug-in has different structure and different file names, so I cant pin point the exact file that I open, maybe it will not work for you, but if you are going to edit a plug-in, you have to go to wp-content, and locate the name of the plug-in then start hunting by opening each files until you find it, be careful tho, each file is connected to other files, so before you do some editing, make sure to back-up the original files, and read the code well.